# What package to use if Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication is now deprecated?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net WebApi project and some packages (eg. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication) are now flagged as deprecated.

What are the alternative packages that should be used?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targetting?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel .net 8.0

Answer (score 7):

I guess you mean  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/2.2.0) is deprecated.

Have a look at [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-package-references-for-removed-assemblies) , and I suggest you use :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
```

You can read [ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.

Comment: This is also marked as deprecated in the following site:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/net-package-deprecation.md

Answer (score 3):

To know the recommended Identity packages, create a new test ASP.NET Core app (latest version) in Visual Studio and in the **Authentication type** input, select **Individual Accounts** - [see link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).

On the app's **NuGet Package Manager for Solution** you will find the pacakages. See below image:

[image]

The packages shown are:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the deprecation of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` (2.2) when attempting to add Microsoft Identity to an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API.  After some digging I discovered the following Microsoft Learn Article:

[Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

The key takeaway from this article are the Nuget packages you may need.  Unfortunately, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` is only for securing web apps but you will need `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` or a similar NuGet package to secure an API.

> ASP.NET Core Identity isn't related to the Microsoft identity
> platform. Microsoft identity platform is:
>
> An evolution of the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) developer
> platform. An alternative identity solution for authentication and
> authorization in ASP.NET Core apps. ASP.NET Core Identity adds user
> interface (UI) login functionality to ASP.NET Core web apps. To secure
> web APIs and SPAs, use one of the following:
>
> - Microsoft Entra ID
> - Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)
> - Duende Identity Server

Which led me to this article

[How to use Identity to secure a Web API backend for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

I am still working on migrating to the new "ASP.NET Core Identity" paradigm for .NET 8.  Comments are welcome.